# Angular doesn't recognize app in IE8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I'm using AngularJS with Asp.NET MVC. I have loaded app.js which includes

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

I then call my controller like so

```
app.controller('OrderController', ['$scope', '$http',... function ($scope, $http...)
```

I am getting this error

Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Anybody Help?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: @WilliamLepinski 1.2.25

Comment: @oztune 
was: <html id="ng-app" ng-app="app"> now because it's <html id="ng-app" data-ng-app="app"> thanks to Srinivas Paila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using data-ng-app instead of ng-app on index.html page, if you are using any  angular version less than < 1.3.0. As angular no more supports IE8 from 1.3.0 version.